# Merging not working inside a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a Time Series data in the form of a list, which has been defined as below

[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Product Name"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 20031031  "Starting duration"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 20160831  "Ending Duration"

[[1]][[4]]
  [1]  0.040816323  0.010141988  0.050318689  0.012804102  0.011378003 
"Series of observations"

I for instance try to merge two series using:  merge(as.zoo(TS1), as.zoo(TS2))

The functionality works fine when its not inside a loop, and is distorted while being used inside a for loop

```
startYear = as.numeric(substr(unlist(TimeSeries[[1]][2]),1,4))

startMonth = as.numeric(substr(unlist(TimeSeries[[1]][2]),5,6))

TS1 = ts(unlist(TimeSeries[[1]][4]), start = c(startYear,startMonth), 
frequency = 12)

TS2 = ts(unlist(TimeSeries[[2]][4]), start = c(startYear,startMonth), 
frequency = 12)

M <- merge(as.zoo(TS1), as.zoo(TS2))
```

No issues seen here in the above merge

issues seen when same code is used inside a For loop,

```
for(I in 1:1)
{
M <- merge(as.zoo(TS1), as.zoo(TS2))
}
```

Why is this happening, and what could possibly be a fix for same

Comment: You need to show us your code

Comment: Post your code so that any of us can recreate the problem, and find a solution, on our own. Try dput(), or check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Edward, I have updated and edited my question, please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think merge is working just fine.

Given the following code:

```
library("zoo")

a = as.zoo(ts(rnorm(5), start = 1981, freq = 12))

b = as.zoo(ts(rnorm(10), start = 1981, freq = 12))

merge(a,b)

for(I in 1:1){
    merge(a,b)
}
```

only the first `merge(a,b)` will print to the console-- in order to print to the console in a for loop you need to call `print` explicitly.

You can see this by executing:

```
for (I in 1:1){
    1:10
}
```

and

```
for (I in 1:1){
    print(1:10)
}
```

*This does not mean that the code inside the loop will not be executed!*

See the output of the following code:

```
library("zoo")

a = as.zoo(ts(rnorm(5), start = 1981, freq = 12))

b = as.zoo(ts(rnorm(10), start = 1981, freq = 12))

new1 <- merge(a,b)

for(I in 1:1){
    new2 <- merge(a,b)
}

new1
new2
```

Output:

```
                  a          b
1981(1)   0.2137495 -0.4148458
1981(2)  -0.1298899 -0.4880588
1981(3)   0.2452036  0.1619693
1981(4)  -0.2251848  0.4866681
1981(5)   1.1049321  1.2171081
1981(6)          NA -0.5852703
1981(7)          NA  1.5238886
1981(8)          NA -0.7583958
1981(9)          NA -0.2972132
1981(10)         NA -0.4476471
                  a          b
1981(1)   0.2137495 -0.4148458
1981(2)  -0.1298899 -0.4880588
1981(3)   0.2452036  0.1619693
1981(4)  -0.2251848  0.4866681
1981(5)   1.1049321  1.2171081
1981(6)          NA -0.5852703
1981(7)          NA  1.5238886
1981(8)          NA -0.7583958
1981(9)          NA -0.2972132
1981(10)         NA -0.4476471
```